# Can a thread waiting on a condititionable variable be woken up by a signal emitted before he was waiting

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, conditional-statements

Is there any chance that a thread `t` waiting on a conditional variable `cond` gets woken up by another thread `t'` (where `t'` might actually be `t`) signaling before `t` was waiting ?

I've tried making a C program that does this 1000 of times but it never occurs, also I've read the man pages about signal and wait but I can't find an answer.

Here's an example of what it might look like on a single thread

```
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex); //Is there a chance that this wait gets cancelled by the signal above
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a thread waiting on a conditional variable be woken up by a signal emitted before he was waiting.

It can't. However, it can be woken up by a [spurious wakeup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) and one won't know the difference.

The waiting code must wait for a change in the shared state, condition variable wakeup is a hint that the shared state may have changed and must be re-evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

No. The `...signal(&cond)` function does not do anything at all if there is no other thread already waiting.